# Net Core Docker Container API. The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssl, https, docker-compose

The communication between a Web App Document Manager and Web API Document Uploader both in docker containers using HTTPS is not working. I was following the recommendation below on how we can use https in docker containers. I am assuming that I have to sort it out the SSL certificate in the API only.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6199

Interesting point is that the https in the Web App Document Manager is working correctly out of the box, when I open the Web App in the browser the https is fine. I am very confused.

I created the documentuploader.pfx  file as explained in this link https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md

However I got the response "A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.", therefore I exported the one already existing named localhost.pfx, but it didn't work. I checked the password, but is correct.

When I run the containers using docker compose I get the following error.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
  HResult=0x80070056
  Message=The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect.
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
  StackTrace:
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.UnixPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(SafePasswordHandle password)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(OpenSslPkcs12Reader pfx, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts, Exception& openSslException)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<BindAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.
...

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at DocumentUploader.Program.Main(String[] args)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Internal.Cryptography.Pal.UnixPkcs12Reader.VerifyAndDecrypt(System.ReadOnlySpan<char>, System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>)
    Internal.Cryptography.Pal.UnixPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle)

Inner Exception 1:
CryptographicException: The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect.
```

My docker compose is

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  documentmanager:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentmanager
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44349   
      # Do not create development certificate in an environment that will be distributed.
      #- DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51218:80"
      - "44349:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Document Manager/Dockerfile
  documentuploader:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentuploader
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44335
      # Do not create development certificate in an environment that will be distributed.
      #- DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51217:80"
      - "44335:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocumentUploader/Dockerfile

networks:
  doc_manager:
    driver: bridge
```

My secret file in documentuploader api project is

```
    "Kestrel": {
      "Certificates": {
        "Default": {
          "Path": "/root/.aspnet/https/documentuploader.pfx",
          "Password": "PASSWORD IS HERE"
        }
      }
    }
```

My DocumentUploader.pfx is copied to /root/.aspnet/https folder in the container.

When I check if the password is correct using openssl program, the content displayed is

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2000
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: <key bag here>, Iteration 2000
PKCS7 Encrypted data: <PKCS7 here>, Iteration 2000
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00
    friendlyName: IIS Express Development Certificate
subject=CN = localhost

issuer=CN = localhost

---BEGIN CERIFICATE---
```

Any help on it?

Answer (score 0):

if you have followed the instructions https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md, the following docker compose works in my case:

> version: '3.5'
>
> services:
>
> dockerex4:
>
> ```
> image: dockerex4image
> container_name: DockerEx4
> environment:
>   - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development      
>   - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
>
>   # If you instead choose to copy cert in Dockerfile, you don't need volumes
>   #- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/DockerEx4.pfx
>   #- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword
> ports:
>   - 9000:80
>   - 9001:443
> volumes:   
>   - C:\Users\rwilliams\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
>   - C:\Users\rwilliams\source\repos\slnDragAndDrop\Artifacts\certs:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
> ```

NOTE: One discrepancy in those documents and my docker-compose is:

> dotnet user-secrets -p aspnetapp\aspnetapp.csproj set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "crypticpassword"

Implying that in your secrets, the "Default" should be "Development". Sorry about the blank lines in the code.
You shouldn't need both volumes and ASPNETCORE_Kestrel environment variables.
also non-standard in my approach is I chose to specify a volume certs directory under my solution root.

EDIT: Also, you most likely have the wrong certificate. The Friendly name should be "ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate" not "IIS Development..."